# To "wow" or not to "wow"

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

Had an argument with my wife regarding the propriety of using the expression "wow". It all started when I blurted out the word in astonishment when the preacher mentioned a negative observation. He mentioned that a well known religious leader wrote in a column a negative statement, "how could our country (not the U.S.) claim to be Christian and yet be so corrupt..". I could not help but blurt out "Wow". My wife reacted and whispered to me that wow can only be used as a reaction to something positive. Is she correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, she is not correct. *Wow* is just an expression of excitement or surprise. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wow).